# Como resolver conflito de merge com git?

Tags: git

Tive um problema de conflito merge no git. Este problema aconteceu quando duas pessoas estavam realizando as mesmas modificações no mesmo arquivo. A primeira pessoa fez o commit e eu fui fazer outro commit após ela. O git recusou e eu tentei mais três vezes. Na quarta vez o git deixou o commit ser realizado, porém o sistema web teve uma parte quebrada.

Sendo assim eu realizei um revert em um commit que estava funcionando e após isso, realizei um checkout para o mesmo commit que estava funcionando. Mas agora quando dou git push, aparece que o diretório esta vazio e não tem nada para subir.

Alguém tem alguma solução para que o repositório volte a funcionar normalmente ? 
Obrigada.

Comment: O master é um terceiro ramo, ou é um dos vossos?

Comment: primeiro detalhe muito importante, sempre faça pull antes de push. Outra dica para evitar esse tipo de situação é usar git stash para colocar as alterações em uma pilha caso seja necessário recuperalas depois disso.

Comment: O master é um ramo meu. Obrigada pela dica @pmargreff.          Eu consegui resolver. Usei o seguinte comando git push -f origin <commit> :master. Obrigada pelos comentários.

Comment: Você pode responder sua própria pergunta nesse caso, assim você ajuda os que tiverem o mesmo problema no futuro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu consegui resolver.                                                    Usei o seguinte comando git push -f origin  :master                                                                Assim a minha branch remota volta para o commit desejado e quando eu clonar o projeto vou começar a partir desse commit.